# Install new software hangs and crashes Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I inherited an RCP app that has a structure that I've never seen before. It has product definition, but there is no product defining plugin - the one that implements org.eclipse.core.runtime.products. Is that a valid configuration? When I select Help -> About -> Installation Details nothing happens and I get NPE at org.eclipse.ui.internal.about.InstallationDialog:221. Also when I select Help -> Install New Software.., RCP hangs indefinitely. What would cause this behavior?

**Edit:**
This was issue on Linux, apparently RCP doesn't work there at the moment. However, on Windows, in instance that doesn't have installation enabled I see that there is no product included in the build, just the feature. In another instance where install feature is working, product is defined. Can RCP be created without product? Screenshot below shows the details and the one on the left does not have install functionality and the one on the right does.[image]

Comment: For some things like 'headless' applications you can get away with just using `org.eclipse.core.runtime.applications` to define an app. Trying to diagnose a problem like this is far too broad for a Stack Overflow question.

Comment: @greg-449 I edited OP with more information